# Suggested table structure for one level deep nested comment?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I want to build a comment system for my posts. For now it will be one level deep only, means comment and its reply.
After reading various article on web, there is 2 suggested way to make your table structure.

**1. Using two tables**

```
//comments table

-id
-post_id
-user_id
-comment
-created_at
-updated_at
-deleted_at

//replies table

-id
-comment_id
-user_id
-comment
-created_at
-updated_at
-deleted_at
```

and then one to many relationship between these 2 tables. Now second approach

**2. Using one table**

```
//comments table

-id
-post_id
-user_id
-comment
-parent_id     //this is important
-created_at
-updated_at
-deleted_at
```

In this second approach, for top level comment, parent_id can be set `NULL` .

What is your suggested way to do this?

I think first one is more normalized version while second one give me flexibility of increasing the replies nested level in future, So for any reason if I plan to increase the level of nesting for comment system I do not have to change database structure any more.

Also, if possible link any article which has explained the logic of fetching and re-arranging the comment in correct order for the second table structure mentioned above.

Comment: In what way is solution 2 less normalized?  Just because it only has 1 table does not prove that it is less normalized.  What normal form does it deviate from that solution 1 does not deviate from?

Answer (score 2):

The first way is overly complex. You end up having two tables, which means that comments and comment's comments are different entities and treated as such. It means double the load in term of work and lines of code.

The second wayallows you to treat any comment the same way and is as easy to implement, the only difference being that instead of checking for any reply having the id of the comment you are currently treating as its `comment_id`, you check for any comment that has it as its `parent_id`.

The plus sides are that you can handle as many layers of commenting as you want, or not set any limit at all, and since all the entities there are comments, you can treat them the same way. It's also easier if you want to upgrade/correct something : do all the changes once.